# Error while trying to call method

Tags: c#, methods, call, reflection.emit, system.reflection

I have this code:

```
var work = new DynamicMethod("work", null, Type.EmptyTypes);
            var il = work.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a");
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[]{typeof(string)}));
            var d = (Action)work.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
            d();
```

I'm just trying to create new method via System.Reflection.Emit. But it throws me this error:

```
Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

Does anybody know how must I repair it to working or where's error? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are missing a call that emits return:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[]{typeof(string)}));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I thought that in sub method there will be not needed to add 'ret'. I have just one question. Some time before it printed me 'Operation could destabilize runtime'. Why?

Comment: @user35443 I am not sure why you may be seeing the "could destabilize" message, but [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2009/06/07/operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-reflection-emit-and-common-pitfalls.aspx) might be related to the issue that you describe.

Comment: It's not that I was looking for, but I have solved that problem jet. Just one small question: is Ldarg_0 in constructor 'this' object?

Comment: @user35443 Yes, `Ldarg_0` refers to the implicit `this` parameter of the constructor.